# Issues with JQuery Validation second time filling out a form. (JQuery Steps)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I am using [JQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) for my registration form. The steps I'm using is:  Personal > Company > Cofirm. I want my errormessages to show up in "placeholder" if the textbox is empty and show a [Toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/) if the textbox has content.

All this works perfectly the first time I debug. All my custom messages shows up, Toastr's works fine. 
But if I try to register another user a second time, my custom messages gets lost, it shows the standard messages in the placeholders, but if I have, for example, entered an invalid email, I don't get any messages but the textbox gets red and I can't go to next step.
Even if I stop debugging and restart it, the toastr's and custom messages are gone. If I restart my computer, it works the first time again.

I've read about event delegation and I'm guessing it has something to do with that, but my problem is that my events are JQuery Steps events, like onStepChanging, onFinished etc, and I'm not sure how to handle the delegation for those.

This is my Ajax-form. _RegisterDetails will generate a table with all information entered in the first two steps:

```
<div id="steps-body-container" class="animated fadeInDown">


    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_RegisterDetails", "Account", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "post",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "ajaxContent",
        LoadingElementId = "loading"
        }, new { defaultButton = "next-button" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <h3>Användare</h3>
        <fieldset class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="text-center">Fyll i användaruppgifter</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="sm-empty-div"></div>
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
            <div class="row register-textbox">
                <div class="col-md-6 pull-left form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                    </span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SurName, new {@class = "form-control user-textbox-left-1", placeholder = "Förnamn", @type = "SurName"})
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 pull-right form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                    </span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new {@class = "form-control user-textbox-right-1", placeholder = "Efternamn", @type = "LastName"})
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row register-textbox">
                <div class="col-md-6 pull-left form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                    </span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new {@class = "form-control user-textbox-left-2", placeholder = "Email", @type = "EmailAddress"})
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 pull-right form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    </span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new {@class = "form-control user-textbox-right-2", placeholder = "Telefonnummer", @type = "PhoneNumber"})
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row register-textbox">
                <div class="col-md-6 pull-left form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i>
                    </span>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new {@class = "form-control user-textbox-left-3", placeholder = "Lösenord", @type = "Password"})
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 pull-right form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                    </span>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new {@class = "form-control user-textbox-right-3", placeholder = "Bekräfta lösenord", @type = "Password"})
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <h3>Företag</h3>
            <fieldset class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="text-center">Fyll i företagsuppgifter</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="sm-empty-div"></div>
                @Html.ValidationSummary()
                <div class="row register-textbox">
                    <div class="col-md-12 pull-left form-group input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                        </span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new {@class = "form-control comp-texbox-1", placeholder = "Namn på företag"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row register-textbox">
                    <div class="col-md-6 pull-left form-group input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i>
                        </span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Street, new {@class = "form-control comp-texbox-left-2", placeholder = "Gatuadress"})
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 pull-right form-group input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                        </span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ZipCode, new {@class = "form-control comp-texbox-right-2", placeholder = "Postnummer"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row register-textbox">
                    <div class="col-md-6 pull-left form-group input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
                        </span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new {@class = "form-control comp-texbox-left-3", placeholder = "Stad"})
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 pull-right form-group input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                        </span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Country, new {@class = "form-control comp-texbox-right-3", placeholder = "Land"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit-btn" defaultbutton="next-button" style="display: none" />
            </fieldset>
        <h3>Bekräfta</h3>
        <fieldset class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="text-center">Bekräfta dina uppgifter</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="sm-empty-div"></div>
            <div id="ajaxContent">
            </div>
            <div id="loading"><i class="fa fa-4x fa-cog fa-spin"></i>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }

</div>
```

And here is my Steps script, with my validate and Ajax-call that saves information to DB.

$('#submit-btn').trigger("click"); Triggers the submitbutton's click-function, since Steps generate it's own buttons for next and finish, I had to make clicking next between second and third step the same thing as clicking submit on form.

```
var registrationModel;
var form = $("#form0").show();

//Runs on Successful Ajax-post.
function RegisterSuccess(surName){
    toastr.options = {
        closeButton: "true",
        preventDuplicates: "true",
        showDuration: "400",
        hideDuration: "400",
        timeOut: "5000",
        showEasing: "swing",
        hideEasing: "linear",
        showMethod: "slideDown",
        hideMethod: "slideUp"
    };
    toastr.success("Ditt konto skapades korrekt. Välkommen till Mina Sidor, " + surName + "!");
}

$("#form0").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    transitionEffectSpeed: 700,
    showFinishButtonAlways: false,
    onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
        //Allow backtracking between second and first step.
        if (currentIndex === 1 && newIndex === 0) {
            return true;
        }

        //
        if (currentIndex === 2 && newIndex === 1) {
            $(".content").animate({
                height: "0px"
            }, 1000);
        }
        return form.valid();
    },
    onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex) {
        var priorTab = $("#form0-t-" + priorIndex);
        priorTab.removeClass("error");

        if (priorIndex === 1 && currentIndex === 2) {
            $(function () {
                $('#submit-btn').trigger("click");
            });
            $(".content").animate({
                height: "500px"
            }, 1000);
        }
    },

    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
        registrationModel = {
            SurName: document.getElementById("SurName").value,
            LastName: document.getElementById("LastName").value,
            Email: document.getElementById("Email").value,
            PhoneNumber: document.getElementById("PhoneNumber").value,
            Password: document.getElementById("Password").value,
            Name: document.getElementById("Name").value,
            Street: document.getElementById("Street").value,
            ZipCode: document.getElementById("ZipCode").value,
            City: document.getElementById("City").value,
            Country: document.getElementById("Country").value
        };

        //Save information to DB
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveRegisterDetailsToDb")',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(registrationModel),
            dataType: "text",
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === "success") {
                    RegisterSuccess(registrationModel.SurName);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Customer")';
                        window.location.href = url;
                    }, 5000);
                }
            },
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true
}).validate({

    rules: {
        SurName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
            //textonly: true
        },
        LastName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
            //textonly: true
        },
        Email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        PhoneNumber: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            minlength: 7
        },
        Password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        },
        ConfirmPassword: {
            equalTo: "#Password"
        },
        Name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
            //textonly: true
        },
        Street: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4
        },
        ZipCode: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        City: {
            required: true,
            //textonly: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        Country: {
            required: true,
            //textonly: true,
            minlength: 2
        }
    },
    //Sorry for all the swedish in the messages. :)
    messages: {
        SurName: {
            required: "Skriv i ditt förnamn här.",
            minlength: "Ditt förnamn måste innehålla minst 2 bokstäver."
            //textonly: true
        },
        LastName: {
            required: "Skriv i ditt efternamn här.",
            minlength: "Ditt efternamn måste innehålla minst 2 bokstäver"
            //textonly: true
        },
        Email: {
            required: "Skriv i din email här.",
            email: "Din email måste vara i ett korrekt format, {XX@XX.XX}"
        },
        PhoneNumber: {
            required: "Skriv i ditt telefonnummer här.",
            number: "Ditt telefonnummer får endast bestå av siffror.",
            minlength: "Ditt telefonnummer måste innehålla minst 7 siffror."
        },
        Password: {
            required: "Skriv i ditt lösenord här.",
            minlength: "Ditt lösenord måste innehålla minst 6 tecken."
        },
        ConfirmPassword: {
            equalTo: "Lösenorden stämmer ej överens. Var vänlig kontrollera stavning."
        },
        Name: {
            required: "Skriv i ditt företagsnamn här.",
            minlength: "Ditt företag måste innehålla minst 2 tecken."
            //textonly: true
        },
        Street: {
            required: "Skriv i företagsadressen här.",
            minlength: "Adressen måste innehålla minst 2 tecken."
        },
        ZipCode: {
            required: "Skriv i postnummer här.",
            number: "Ditt postnummer får endast innehålla siffror.",
            minlength: "Ditt postnummer måste bestå av minst 5 siffror."
        },
        City: {
            required: "Skriv i staden här.",
            //textonly: true,
            minlength: "Stad måste innehålla minst 2 bokstäver."
        },
        Country: {
            required: "Skriv i landet här.",
            //textonly: true,
            minlength: "Landet måste innehålla minst 2 bokstäver."
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        //Placing error messages in placeholders when empty.
        if (element.val() === "") {
            element.attr("placeholder", error.text());
        }
        //Pop toastr for error message when textbox has content.
        if(element.val() !== "") {
            toastr.options = {
            positionClass: 'toast-right-center', //Custom position.
            closeButton: "true",
            preventDuplicates: "true",
            showDuration: "400",
            hideDuration: "400",
            timeOut: "10000",
            showEasing: "swing",
            hideEasing: "linear",
            showMethod: "fadeIn",
            hideMethod: "fadeOut"
        };
            toastr.error(error.text());

        }
    }
});
```

So, my final question is:
Why is this only working once, and if it has to do with event delegation, what part am I supposed to bind to what?

**UPDATE:**

When I debug the site, some old code is generated, for example the line

```
<div id="loading"><i class="fa fa-4x fa-cog fa-spin"></i></div>
```

is in the browser

```
<div id="loading"><i class="fa fa-4x fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i></div>
```

which is the icon I used before. Can this have something to do with my original issue? The div in question is located inside the third step.
I've noticed that when the site behaves as it should be, the cog-icon is being used.
I'm completely baffled by this, so hopefully someone have an idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to execute your Steps script again following the ajax post back to reassign the events to the returned new HTML.

Comment: hmm, do you mean that I should make the steps script to a variable and call itself right after the callback or a shortened version? Sorry, I'm quite new to jquery and javascript all together.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, you can put the  $("#form0").steps call into a function and call that when the page has loaded and then from either the AJAX success or complete method.

Comment: It didn't work for me, I got the same results. but when I took a closer look at my html in devtools, it shows code that I've changed, for example icons that I'm not using anymore is still present. I'm really puzzled how that is happening. I've rechecked and rebuilt over and over again, but the old code does not go away. I'm guessing my problem has something to do with that.

Comment: For example: 
<div id="loading"><i class="fa fa-4x fa-cog fa-spin"></i></div>
in my code becomes:
<dv id="loading"><i class="fa fa-4x fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i></div>
Which is my old icon. Is this a cache issue or ajax issue perhaps?

Comment: Not too sure I'm afraid, I wouldn't have thought it would be the ajax. Have you tried F5 in the browser, that should hopefully clear any cached data.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Ctrl+F5 but the old code is still there.

Comment: At this moment, I'm very ashamed to admit that I had two versions of Register-view, one regular and one partial. We're using partialview and I was programming in the regular one... It worked sometimes because I sometimes debugged straight into the regular view, but when I clicked link on the site, I came to the partial view that wasn't updated. All works perfectly now. Sorry for wasting your time!